# what is meaning of "readlimit" parameter at mark method in java?

Tags: java, buffer

```
BufferedInputStream.mark(int readlimit)
```

I read java doc but I don't understand when we use this parameter "`readlimit`"
in this code, I don't understand what's different between mark(1)  or mark(100)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
String s="123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSDVWXYZ";
byte byteArray[]=s.getBytes();
ByteArrayInputStream BArrayIS=new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
BufferedInputStream BIS=new BufferedInputStream(BArrayIS);
BIS.mark(1);
System.out.println(BIS.read());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It has no effect because [BufferedInputStream.mark](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html#mark(int)) method effects `` which is used in [reset](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#reset())  method that you don't use.

> Repositions this stream to the position at the time the mark method